# Does gurobi do minimum changes (minimal perturbation) when starting from a partial solution?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I know that in gurobi I can start from an initial solution. i.e. after solving an LP using

```
   m.optimize()
```

for model m, I can change some constraints and either use

```
   m.reset()
   m.optimize()
```

to find a new solution for the LP from scratch or just call

```
   m.optimize()
```

to find a new solution from the initial solution.

My question is that when gurobi starts from an initial solution does it do minimal changes (to the variables) required to get the new solution?

I think this is a minimal perturbation problem. If gurobi does not do this by default, is there any-way to inform gurobi to do minimal changes?

FURTHER COMMENTS:
 I understand that warm start could be faster but will the changes in variables be minimal. For example, the objective function is

```
  maximize(i1+i2+i3+i4)
```

and the initial set of constraint is such that only

```
  i1,i2 can be set as 1 and i3,i4 as 0.
```

Now the constraints change and the new solution (still only 2 variables can be set as 1) can be either

```
  i1, i3 as 1 (or) i3, i4 as 1.
```

Could gurobi optimizer end up selecting the solution with minimal change i1, i3 as 1?

Also if another solution was

```
   i1,i2 as 1
```

will gurobi choose that as that solution is exactly the same as existing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is known as a *warm start*.  Most modern linear programming solvers, including Gurobi Optimizer, use a warm start when you modify a model and call the `optimize()` function.  With minor changes, it is usually much faster to solve the model using the warm start.  However, if you make substantial changes, a warm start may be slower than solving the model from scratch.  Gurobi Optimizer also uses a warm start for MIP models.

With Gurobi Optimizer, you can also specify start values via the `Start` attribute, or for LP models via the primal and dual start attributes (`PStart` and `DStart`, respectively).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that warm start could be faster but will the changes in variables be minimal. For example, the objective function is `maximize(i1+i2+i3+i4)` and the initial set of constraint is such that only `i1,i2` can be set as 1 and `i3,i4` as 0. Now the constraints change and the new solution (still only 2 variables can be set as 1) can be either `i1, i3` as 1 (or) `i3, i4` as 1. Could gurobi optimizer end up selecting the solution with minimal change `i1, i3` as 1? Also if another solution was `i1,i2` as 1  will gurobi choose that as that solution is exactly the same as existing?

Comment: This will depend on how the model is built. If you are simply changing coefficients in the matrix, you will get warm start automatically.  If you are adding new constraints, then you may or may not get the warm start.  If you don't, you can always explicitly set the `Start` attribute on the variables.

Comment: But does warm start ensure minimal perturbation? Even if I assume that warm start is happening for sure, is there anyway to inform the solver that I want the new solution to be as close to the initial solution as possible? Or does warm start in general produce a new solution as close to the existing solution as possible?

Comment: The solution will be optimal with respect to the objective function. There is no guarantee it is "close" to the old solution.  The only way to get a solution that is "close" to another is to define an objective function that minimizes the deviation from the original solution.